# Unable to Install Remote database locally using phpAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, local, create-table

Some of you are going to wonder which tree I fell out of, but here's my problem.

MacOSX 10.8.3 MAMP installed on Mac fine. Using Safari 6.0.3

PHP 5.4.10. Can't see what version of MySQL, it's the latest (March 2013).

Got a backup of remote MySQL database taken with phpAdmin and downloaded as a zip to Mac.

The problem is that using phpAdmin on my Mac I simply can't get the MySQL database installed locally.

I have tried an Import without first setting up a database locally. I was  expecting the import to bring along both the data and the database tables. However the result of an Import is a blank page in phpAdmin with no feedback as to what has happened.

I then created a local database to receive the remote backup file. After creating, this shows up in phpAdmin as being without tables, as expected.

The result is the same. A white page in phpAdmin with nothing to show what has happened.

Does this all mean that to install the backup database locally I first have to create a mirror image on my Mac with all tables defined? This will be a very tedious exercise if so.

I'm obviously missing some vital step in the process. Enlightenment will be gracious indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Blank white page is a traditional php error page :)

If it were me, I would save the SQL into a file (`mydb.sql`) and then try importing from mysql command line. If that works, you know it is a phpmyadmin issue, rather than your database, or mysql.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Not sure how to use the MySQL command line, but I will have a try.

Comment: Does your answer confirm that the backup I made with phpAdmin and downloaded to my Mac DOES include the tables AND the data?

Comment: No, it is possible you backed up only data, or only tables. Without seeing code, it is impossible for me to know what your backup contains. My suggestion is simply to narrow down where the problem lies.